# WCF hosting with windows Service, client cannot see endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I'm trying to build a test application to test wcf and learn more on it:

I wrote a WCF service and hosted this in a windows service. Here's my `app.config` from the windows service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>    
     <services>
        <service name="WCFLibrary.CalculatorService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
           <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                 <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
              </baseAddresses>
           </host>
           <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
           <endpoint 
               address=""
               binding="wsHttpBinding"
               contract="WCFLibrary.ICalculator" />
           <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
           <endpoint 
               address="mex"
               binding="mexHttpBinding"
               contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
               <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now I want to build a client app to consume the WCF service. But when I go to `Add Service Reference` it gives me an error it can't reach the endpoint. I can see the service running from service manager. I did a test by doing a Debug from VS. During the debug the client was able to see the endpoint. But if I stop and Debug go back to the service manager, the client can't see the endpoint.

What could be wrong? Any clues please?

**EDIT1**

**Windows service** (`Service1.cs`)

```
namespace WindowsService
{
   public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
   {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

        public Service1()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void onDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                 serviceHost.Close();
                 serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
namespace WindowsService
{
    public  class CalculatorWindowsService :ServiceBase
    {
        public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

        public CalculatorWindowsService()
        {
            // Name the Windows Service
            ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Main()
        {
//#if DEBUG
//           Service1 myservice = new Service1();
//           myservice.onDebug();
//           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
//#else
            //  CalculatorWindowsService calc = new CalculatorWindowsService();
            ServiceBase.Run(new CalculatorWindowsService());
//#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the url of your service in local web browser to see any error message; check event viewer to see any complains; and check your firewall inbound and outbound rules to see if port 8000 is actually open for business.

Comment: @AndyH: In internet explorer it gives me 'The Page cannot be displayed' with 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'

Comment: In the eventviewer it is showing me that the service has started & if I stop from the service manager it shows me the service has stopped successfully

Comment: Can you connect to your service using the WCF Test Client? What URL are you using from your client to connect to the service? And if you enter `http://servername:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service?wsdl` in a browser - do you get to see the WSDL of the service?

Comment: @user726720 you'll find that you cannot reach the WSDL (as marc suggested). What do you conclude from that fact?

Comment: using "http://servername:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service?wsdl" in a browser says's page not found while running from the service manager. I'm using the same URL from the client, which it says it can't reach.

Comment: I stopped the from the service manager and did a test from the WCF project using test client. It works fine.

Comment: since you are using Windows service to host WCF service, would you show the codes that activate WCF service?

Comment: I did the same test in another laptop it's working fine. I'm wondering why it didn't work in my first laptop. I checked the firewall etc. everything seems alright. I have no clue why, but finally got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code above. The same code is working in my second laptop. So something to do with the OS  or IE on my first laptop. Will check that out.